# Multi identifier error in trigger function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger function that create for inserted. I have two stockTransaction and StokItem in the code I wanted to display the changes on StockItem and I succeeded it. But now I simply change the column BuyinPrice of my Item table which is third table after updating StokItem table.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StockTransactionInserted]
ON  [dbo].[StockTransaction]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
@IdItem int,    
@IdStorage int,
@TransactionType char(1),
@Code char(1),
@Quantity decimal(18, 8),
@UnitPrice decimal(18, 8),
@Discount decimal(18, 8),
@FatAltDiscount decimal(18, 8),
@VAT decimal(18, 8)

SELECT 
@IdItem = IdItem, 
@IdStorage = IdStorage,
@TransactionType = TransactionType,
@Code = Code,  
@Quantity = Quantity,
@UnitPrice = UnitPrice,
@Discount = Discount,
@FatAltDiscount = FatAltDiscount,
@VAT = VAT
FROM inserted

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StockItem WHERE IdItem = @IdItem AND IdStorage = @IdStorage)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StockItem (IdItem, IdStorage, TOP_GIRIS_MIK, TOP_CIKIS_MIK)
    VALUES (@IdItem, @IdStorage, 0, 0)
END



UPDATE StockItem
SET
TOP_GIRIS_MIK = TOP_GIRIS_MIK + CASE WHEN @Code = 'G' THEN @Quantity ELSE 0 END,
TOP_GIRIS_TUT = TOP_GIRIS_TUT + CASE WHEN @Code = 'G' THEN (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) * @Quantity ELSE 0 END,

TOP_CIKIS_MIK = TOP_CIKIS_MIK + CASE WHEN @Code = 'C' THEN @Quantity ELSE 0 END,
TOP_CIKIS_TUT = TOP_CIKIS_TUT + CASE WHEN @Code = 'C' THEN (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) * @Quantity ELSE 0 END,

ORT_BR_FIAT = CASE WHEN ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) + @Quantity) = 0 THEN (ORT_BR_FIAT + (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100))) / 2 ELSE ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) * ORT_BR_FIAT + (@Quantity * (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)))) / ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) + @Quantity) END,

SON_GIR_BR_FIAT = (CASE WHEN @UnitPrice=0 OR @TransactionType != 'A' THEN SON_GIR_BR_FIAT ELSE @UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100) END),
SON_GIR_NET_FIAT =  (CASE WHEN @UnitPrice=0 OR @TransactionType != 'A' THEN SON_GIR_NET_FIAT ELSE (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) + (@UnitPrice * @VAT/100) END)
WHERE IdItem = @IdItem AND IdStorage = @IdStorage

UPDATE Item
SET BuyingPrice = StockItem.SON_GIR_BR_FIAT where item_id = @IdItem
END
```

Actually Update StokItem is working it is not problem but when i want to update my Item table in here

```
UPDATE Item
SET BuyingPrice = StockItem.SON_GIR_BR_FIAT where item_id = @IdItem
```

It says Multi identifier error for StockItem.SON_GIR_BR_FIAT column.

Can you please help me! Thanks!

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows, depending on how many rows the original statement affected. Your trigger fails to work in the latter case.

Comment: `UPDATE Item SET BuyingPrice = StockItem.SON_GIR_BR_FIAT where item_id = @IdItem` refers to a column (`SON_GIR_BR_FIAT`) in a table (`StockItem`) that is not used in the `update`. You seem to be expecting the database to find the table, without a `from` clause, and pick a suitable row to get the column value from. SQL Server is not very good at [rhabdomancy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhabdomancy). Tip: Including the DDL for the tables would help us understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, it should work!
The table Inserted can contain 0, 1 or multiple rows. So, you need to use a CURSOR with the rows affected in order to UPDATE the table StockItem and Item row by row.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[StockTransactionInserted]
ON  [dbo].[StockTransaction]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
  @IdItem int,    
  @IdStorage int,
  @TransactionType char(1),
  @Code char(1),
  @Quantity decimal(18, 8),
  @UnitPrice decimal(18, 8),
  @Discount decimal(18, 8),
  @FatAltDiscount decimal(18, 8),
  @VAT decimal(18, 8)



DECLARE curStockTransaction CURSOR FOR   
SELECT IdItem, IdStorage, TransactionType, Code, Quantity, UnitPrice, Discount, FatAltDiscount, VAT
FROM inserted

OPEN curStockTransaction
FETCH NEXT FROM curStockTransaction INTO @IdItem, @IdStorage, @TransactionType, @Code, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @Discount, @FatAltDiscount, @VAT
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StockItem WHERE IdItem = @IdItem AND IdStorage = @IdStorage)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO StockItem (IdItem, IdStorage, TOP_GIRIS_MIK, TOP_CIKIS_MIK)
    VALUES (@IdItem, @IdStorage, 0, 0)
  END

  UPDATE StockItem
  SET
    TOP_GIRIS_MIK = TOP_GIRIS_MIK + CASE WHEN @Code = 'G' THEN @Quantity ELSE 0 END,
    TOP_GIRIS_TUT = TOP_GIRIS_TUT + CASE WHEN @Code = 'G' THEN (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) * @Quantity ELSE 0 END,

    TOP_CIKIS_MIK = TOP_CIKIS_MIK + CASE WHEN @Code = 'C' THEN @Quantity ELSE 0 END,
    TOP_CIKIS_TUT = TOP_CIKIS_TUT + CASE WHEN @Code = 'C' THEN (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) * @Quantity ELSE 0 END,

    ORT_BR_FIAT = CASE WHEN ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) + @Quantity) = 0 THEN (ORT_BR_FIAT + (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100))) / 2 ELSE ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) * ORT_BR_FIAT + (@Quantity * (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)))) / ((TOP_GIRIS_MIK - TOP_CIKIS_MIK) + @Quantity) END,

    SON_GIR_BR_FIAT = (CASE WHEN @UnitPrice=0 OR @TransactionType != 'A' THEN SON_GIR_BR_FIAT ELSE @UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100) END),
    SON_GIR_NET_FIAT =  (CASE WHEN @UnitPrice=0 OR @TransactionType != 'A' THEN SON_GIR_NET_FIAT ELSE (@UnitPrice * (1- @Discount/100)) + (@UnitPrice * @VAT/100) END)
  WHERE
    IdItem = @IdItem AND IdStorage = @IdStorage

  UPDATE Item
  SET
    BuyingPrice = StockItem.SON_GIR_BR_FIAT
  FROM Item
  JOIN StockItem ON (StockItem.IdItem = Item.item_id)
  where
    item_id = @IdItem

  FETCH NEXT FROM curStockTransaction INTO @IdItem, @IdStorage, @TransactionType, @Code, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @Discount, @FatAltDiscount, @VAT  
END   
CLOSE curStockTransaction
DEALLOCATE curStockTransaction

END
```

Comment: Why is a cursor needed? Wouldn't a set-based solution suffice and likely be more efficient?